# Rspec: engine path helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

routes:

```
Users::Engine.routes.draw do
  get "test/step1", to: "test#step1", as: "step1"
  get "test/step2", to: "test#step2", as: "step2"
end
```

constoller spec:

```
describe Users::Test do
  it "sample" do
    get :test2, use_route: "users"
    response.should redirect_to users.step1_path
  end
end
```

rake routes:

```
Routes for Users::Engine:
  step1 GET    /test/step1(.:format)                    users/test#step1
  step2 GET    /test/step2(.:format)                    users/test#step2
....
```

I have error:

```
Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to users.step1_path
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `users' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_9::Nested_3:0xb7496f8>
```

How I can use engine path helpers like `users.step1_path` in the controller specs?

Comment: what does `$ rake routes` give you?

Comment: @Charles Added `rake routes` output. I have no error when using `user.step1_path` in views or controller. Just when using this helpers in controller specs.

Comment: ok, thanks - and why do you call `users.step1_path` instead of just `step1_path`?

Comment: Because, I have many engines mounted in one app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RSpec routes need to be set to your engines route set rather than the default global Rails.routes for your engines controller tests.

```
describe Users::Test do

  routes { Users::Engine.routes }

  it "sample" do
    get :test2
    response.should redirect_to step1_path
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Rails 4 and Rspec 3. I got it working by including the route helpers in the spec, like this:

```
describe Users::Test do

  include Users::Engine.routes.url_helpers

  it "sample" do
    get :test2
    response.should redirect_to step1_path
  end

end
```

Comment: NOTE: "include" instead of "includes"